# rspec fails even when variables should match

Tags: ruby, rspec

Methods in my class:

```
  def get_class_info
    @class_name = get_class_name
  end

  def get_class_name
    puts "Enter the name for your class. Enter 'done' to return to the main prompt."
    input = gets.chomp
    if input.valid_class_name?
      class_name = input.titleize
    elsif input.downcase == "done"
      run
    else
      puts "Invalid class name."
      get_class_name
    end
    class_name
  end
```

My test:

```
it "stores the name in the @class_name property" do
  expect(cli.class_name).to eq('Song')
  allow(cli).to receive(:gets) {'song'}
  cli.get_class_info
end
```

It fails, saying it expected "Song" but got nil.
If I comment out the expect line and add a pry to the end of the test, querying `cli.class_name` returns `"Song"`!!!

Why is this test failing??

Update: Okay, moving the `expect` line to the *bottom* of the test apparently solved it. But I'm confused because usually the expectation goes before the actual method call. Am I wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but why would you think the expectation comes before the method call? How would that work?

Comment: The `allow` or `expect` lines go before the method call. But for any expectations, where you check the _state_ that occurs as a _result_ of a method call - that needs to go afterwards. Why would `cli.class_name == "Song"` before you call the method `get_class_info`?

Comment: only mock expectations go before

Comment: can you show the part where `cli` is defined? Something like `let(:cli) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner and others. I'm still getting the hang of writing specs, and getting the hang of understanding the kinds of principles you're referring to.